# Exception while executing SQL Query using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, exception, jdbc

I get an exception while executing an sql query using jdbc on NetBeans IDE. I'm able to execute the same query using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express without any errors.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT tcd.RouterCallKey,adc.AgentSkillTargetID,adc.AgentPeripheralNumber,adc.InstrumentPortNumber,adc.ANI,adc.DateTime,adc.TalkTime 
FROM Termination_Call_Detail tcd 
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT tcd1.RouterCallKey, AgentSkillTargetID,AgentPeripheralNumber,InstrumentPortNumber,ANI,DateTime,TalkTime
FROM Termination_Call_Detail AS tcd1 WHERE tcd1.AgentSkillTargetID <>'' 
AND tcd1.TalkTime > 0 AND tcd1.TalkTime <=5 AND RouterCallKey <> 0 AND CallDisposition <>28
AND tcd1.DateTime >= '2011-02-03 12:00:00 AM' AND tcd1.DateTime <= '2011-02-03 11:59:59 PM'
) adc 
ON adc.RouterCallKey = tcd.RouterCallKey AND tcd.CallDisposition in (52) 
AND tcd.DateTime >= '2011-02-03 12:00:00 AM' AND tcd.DateTime <= '2011-02-03 11:59:59 PM' 
AND LEN(tcd.ANI ) > 4
```

Here is the exception:

`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'`.

Comment: I removed as but still I get an exception.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't damaged the query when entering it in the Java code?

Comment: I'm sure, I copied the code from java to sql studio and it is working fine. I think it's a syntax error but I'm not able to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: what is the exception you get after removing `as` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a difference between the two queries. Run the SQL Server Profiler to capture the query or do a System.out.println to display the exact query you are running in Java.  Look out for things like missing spaces like so:

```
"SELECT * FROM" +
"WHERE problem = 'No space between from and where'";
```

Comment: I did a System.out.println & I was surprised that all the query was displayed in a single line which occurs in an exception. How can I read the sql query line by line?

Comment: Thank You! As you mentioned the error was occurring because there was no spacing between lines.

Comment: @loo glad you got it working. I find I have to watch myself or I end up making this mistake frequently.